# I can not pull some data in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a problem.The problem is;

I have a JSON file, I can see the output of this file in "Console.log". But on the sample, I want to get the "data" content, I get the output

```
"cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "test",
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [
    {
     "data": {
      "image/png": "sampledata",
      "text/plain": [
       "<IPython.core.display.Image object>"
      ]

data: 
     [ [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object]
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Could you show the code you used to get the `data` values?

Comment: What browser are you using? (Name + Version) plus, did you try to click on Object? Some (most, if not all) browser consoles collapse object children by default in the console and you can expand them like a treeview.

Comment: Hey Chris, I need you to give me your mail address so I can show you this. I also work on the terminal, not on the browser

Answer (score 1):

`console.log` can't print nested objects, you have to use [util.inspect()](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) native nodejs function (don't forget to require util e.g `const util = require('util')`)

See this [Repl exemple](https://repl.it/repls/ComposedFluidLightweightprocess)

Comment: I do not understand you exactly, do you have a link address that you can give an example?

Comment: You simply import util as a library, and use it to show your JSON, `util.inspect(yourjsonvar)` :)

Comment: var simply = JSON.stringify(require('./test.json'))
I pulled the file like this, how do I edit it?

Comment: Updated my answer with an exemple ;)

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your concern...this exemple is simply there to show the use of `util.inspect` compared to `console.log` I don't know the rest of your code

Comment: I want to show the rest of my codes, so can you give me an address where I can contact you?

Comment: @Plotisaetur, Thank you very much, man, I solved the problem on my own code, I can buy you a beer because you helped: D

Comment: Haha, happy to know that ! With pleasure :) Don't forget to also upvote me if it helped !